# Parent's name of Form.show()

Tags: c#, winforms

I use `Form.Show()` to open a new form

Like this:

```
public Form2()
{
    Form1 fm = new Form1();
    fm.Show();
}
```

How do I get `Form2`'s name when `Form1` has control?

What I am doing is create a `public variable(ex.pFormname)` in `From1`

and set `pFormname = Form2` before the show common like this:

```
public Form2()
{
    Form1.pFormname = "Form2";
    Form1 fm = new Form1();
    fm.Show();
}
```

*Is there any other way except creating a public variable?*

And is there any resource release should I do after closing `Form1`?

Comment: Don't understand what your problem is at all.

Comment: can you explain what is your problem more precisely?

Comment: Why do you want to know the name of the form(form2) which opened a new form (form1)?

Comment: I want to know where Form1 opened from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Form2()
{
     Form1 fm = new Form1();
     Form1.pFormname = this.Text; // this = Form2, Text = the arbitrary name of the form.

     fm.Show();
}
```

This requires you to have a public instance variable or property called pFormname in Form1 class. the 'this' keyword represents the current instance of Form2, and Text is the property which contains the name of the Form.

If you want to access other properties on the parent form, you could pass it as a reference when you instantiate Form1.

```
public Form2()
{
     Form1 fm = new Form1(this); // this = form2.
     fm.Show();
}
```

In Form1 you would have something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 _parentForm;

    public Form1(Form2 parentForm)
    {
        _parentForm = parentForm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And you would call public variables/properties/methods like this:

```
_parentForm.SomeMethod();
```

Comment: Constructor is a very good way to deal with this situation.But i may open Form1 from other then From2. I'll edit my constructor to fit what i want and keep searching other solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use Form instead of Form2, since all forms inherit from Form. You could also implement an interface to ensure that all methods you need from all forms are the present.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the forms Owner property and pick that up in your instance later. For example in the constructor of Form2:

```
public Form2()
{
    Form1 fm = new Form1 {Owner=this};
    fm.Show();
}
```

You use the Owner name in Form1 like this

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += Form1_Load;
        }

         void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text += Owner.Name;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the name of the parent form , you can do so by using

`string s = ParentForm.Name`; // s will contain the name of the parent form

Hope this helps..

If you want to find out , the child ..you can do so by:

`MdiChildren` property.

this will help you to find out , which child forms(Form 2) are contained by currently opened form(Form1).

Refer to this for how to use this exactly:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: In which form, are you trying?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do in that situation is to have a private field in `Form1` and set it equal to `Form2` when you instantiate it like this.

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form _parentForm;

    public Form1(Form f)
    {
        _parentForm = f;
    }
}
```

and when you instantiate `Form1` do like this

```
Form1 fm = new Form1(this) // in the constructor of Form2;
```

after this you will have the reference to the `Form2` in the `Form1`'s _parentForm variable and you can easuily access any of its properties for instance;

```
MessageBox.Show(_parentForm.Name) // in Form1 will show the name of Form2
```

or you can just have a `string` which you set the `this.Name` when you instantiate `Form1` in `Form2`'s constructor

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    private string _parentFormName;

    public Form1(string name)
    {
        _parentForm = f;
    }
}

Form1 fm = new Form1(this.Name) // in the constructor of Form2;
```

and then you can directly call that variable like this

```
MessageBox.Show(_parentFormName);
```